# Are there any spells that make your character younger?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, pathfinder-society

I want to have a character whose a child however your character has to be an adult by Pathfinder rules so i am currently looking for a spell that reduces a characters age. I am aware of spells like reincarnation which makes your character a young adult but i am looking for one that makes your character a child. I am looking for something Pathfinder society legal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pathfinder Society has strict rules about how effects are handled, which prevent any spell-based strategy from working permanently. In PFS play, non-harmful spell effects cannot last between scenarios:

> All spells and effects end at the end of a scenario with the following exceptions: *[healing spells, harmful effects, and four specific spells]*

That’s pages 25–26 of the *Pathfinder Society Roleplaying Guild Guide*. Since childhood age is not a harmful spell effect, you’ll lose any age change effect from a spell at the end of every scenario where you manage to acquire it. And since *permanency* is banned in PFS, there’s no way to avoid losing it.

Furthermore, any permanent childhood effect — from spells or otherwise — would make the character’s age illegal. (PFSRGG, p. 7) Any character that is illegal at the end of a scenario must be reported as dead (p. 23):

> An unplayable character should be marked as dead when reporting the session.

So no matter the way you slice it, trying to make a character *permanently* break the age rules for PFS is a losing proposition.

The *only* way you could manage it is by having a temporary effect that you could resolve before the end of every scenario — this would let you start and end each scenario as a character of legal age. Acquiring such an ability may be prohibitively difficult though — perhaps impossible within PFS rules.

Comment: So a dude that's been the subject of the spell *reincarnate* during a scenario—because that spell isn't of the subschool healing—essentially dies again at the scenario's end?

Answer (score 3):

While there are several spells that *can* reduce a creature's current age—[*Blood of the Night*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy8v33?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Blood-of-the-Night) (2012) includes the spells [*steal years*](http://www.archivesofnethys.com/SpellDisplay.aspx?ItemName=Steal%20Years) et al. that are likely the most straightforward—, few of these spells allow a creature to reduce its age to less than its current age or to less than young adult *à la* the spell [*reincarnate*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reincarnate/).

Nonetheless, the spell [***cyclic reincarnation***](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/c/cyclic-reincarnation/)—a spell that may be legal in Pathfinder Society play, it coming from [*Arcane Anthology*](http://paizo.com/products/btpy9i8l?Pathfinder-Player-Companion-Arcane-Anthology) (2016)—, in part, says, "If the affected creature [i.e. the creature on whom the spell *cyclic reincarnation* has been cast] isn’t a humanoid, there is a 75% chance that the creature returns to life as a youth of its race, gaining the [young creature](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/simple-template-young-cr-1) simple template instead" of the spell's normal effects. Thus a nonhumanoid like an [aasimar](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-aasimar)—an outsider—stands a 75% chance of becoming a young aasimar if it's the subject of a *cyclic reincarnation* spell. (Make sure someone else at the table has the spell prepared *before* suiciding and hoping to come back as Kid Angelkin, though!)

#### Beyond Pathfinder Society play

In this GM's home campaigns, this GM would allow a player who's adamant about playing a creature made young this way to write in the PC's background that the PC was the subject of the spell *cyclic reincarnation* before entering the campaign.

However, typically, in my campaigns, if a player wants his PC to be younger than the minimum age recommended by the core rules, this GM simply says, "Sure. Whatever." The game is far more unbalanced by [old PCs](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/description/), [youth granting a PC no particular mechanical advantages.](https://www.threadless.com/product/2199/forget_youth_what_this_world_could_use_is_a_fountain_of_smart)

---

***Note:*** This GM has personal misgivings about players playing actual little children in a role-playing game that has as its mission statement kill things and take their stuff. *Just sayin'.*

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is **there are no spells that can turn you** ***specifically*** **into a child.** Just because it isn't written in one of the books *specifically* should not stop you.  You just have to get a little creative.  **You may** ***modify*** **some spells reasonably enough to make this possible.**  The spells I'm about to suggest will require your GM to allow for some modification of the spells.

The spell closest to what you're looking for is [*Threefold Aspect*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/threefold-aspect). At its basest description, this spell ages you younger or older into a young adult, an adult, or an elderly adult. This changes your Ability Scores a bit for each form.  You can try consulting your GM to see if you can add "child" to the list and use the [Young Character](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/basics-ability-scores/more-character-options/young-characters/) stat modifications for this effect.

Or, instead of that spell, you could request your GM to allow you to turn the target of [*Bestow Curse*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/bestow-curse) or *Greater Bestow Curse* into a child using  when your character casts it as an alternate effect.  I don't particularly recommend cursing yourself though, as it is a permanent effect until otherwise removed by magical means.

Comment: This is not PFS legal.